# Status 403 when i'm trying to put image with an URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, curl, symfony4

I'm trying to make a Website with Symfony4. I use curl to get the html code from another webpage, and my goal is to get the link of the only image on this website, and display it on mine.

I've tried it from scratch (using Php) with curl and regex. To check the image URL, I print it and it works. I am using a Xampp server.

But now i'm trying to do it with Symfony and i have a 403 status. When I check the code, everything is fine but the image doesn't display. It's weird because if I visite the webpage before showing the image on my website, it works.

I'm  sure that I have the right image URL to display but I don't understand why I must visite the source website to display it on my website.

image.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ img_link }}">
```

image.php

```php
$curl = new Curl();
        $curl->setUserAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.0)');
        $curl->setOpt (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        //$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        $curl->get($this->random_link);
        $this->html_content = $curl->response;
        $curl->close();
```

html page generate

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Donation</h1>
        <img src="https://exemple_link.html/exemple">
</div>
```

error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: looks like a CORS issue, This may help https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/403-cursed-by-cors-d1700cab754 it looks like a similar situation with the headers not being sent. I don't use curl unless I have to, so I don't know what the curl fix would be.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy/download the image, upload it and your sever, and use a relative link instead?

Comment: It looks like protection. Try to put Referer header to request with domain where image is located.